# Refresh a view in backbone js when link is clicked again

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

So I have a set of navigation links at the top of my page.

One of them links to a list of hardware the users owns showing name and description.

1. I click the nav link and my list of hardware if rendered fine.
2. Go into database, change the name of one of the hardware pieces.
3. Now i click the nav link again on the page.  I would expect backbone to
   render the page again. But it doesn't.

I have a message print to the console every time render is called. The second click does not run the render function on the view.

I imagine backbone prevents re rendering the view or calling events when a route that is already open is activated.  Is there any way to get it to rerender the already open view when I click on nav link a second time?

Comment: Did my answer help, or do you still have questions?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that Backbone prevents a route from triggering if it's already on that route.

There are a few solutions.

You could forcefully trigger the route by hijacking the links and calling `router.navigate("route/path", {trigger: true});`.

Or, even better, avoid triggering the router and use an api object. It's something [Derick Bailey has written about here](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/08/28/dont-execute-a-backbone-js-route-handler-from-your-code/). Every click after the first would use the api to re-run the render code, bypassing the Backbone router. You can see a more advanced use of this method in [the bbclonemail app](https://github.com/Foxandxss/bbclonemail).